# Python-docx set the text direction RTL

Tags: python-2.7, python-docx

I am trying to create a docunent with RTL (Right-To-Left) text direction

```
def printExam():

  #get the exam questions 

  rows = db(db.exam_questions.exam == request.vars.exam).select()

  # create the documnet
  document = Document()
  document.add_heading(u"أختبار", 0)

  #for row in rows:
  row = rows[0] 
  run = document.add_paragraph().add_run(str(row.question.questionText).decode( "utf-8" ))
  font = run.font
  font.rtl = True
```

I got the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\web2py-src\gluon\restricted.py", line 227, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "C:/Users/web2py-src/applications/draft/controllers/question.py", line 96, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\web2py-src\gluon\globals.py", line 417, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "C:/Users/web2py-src/applications/draft/controllers/question.py", line 68, in printExam
    font.rtl = True
AttributeError: 'Font' object attribute 'rtl' is read-only
```

Comment: It would be nice if you took the trouble to indent your code correctly.

Comment: What is `font.rtl` currently set to?

Comment: when i print its value : True

Comment: Do you experience an issue if you don't do `font.rtl = True`?

Comment: Seems like that line is not necessary if the value is already `True`.

Comment: Yes, when i remove font.rtl = True, the text displayed with LTR direction

Comment: Very odd. Where exactly is the error being raised? Could you provide a full traceback?

Comment: Updated  the question with the full traceback

Comment: Could it be because you are using a default font for the run?

Comment: Yes, i didn't set a special font , should i ? and if yes how can i do that ?

Comment: Hang on better idea. What version of the library are you using?

Comment: version : python-docx-0.8.6

Comment: Looking at the docs, you probably don't need to set a special Font. Looking at the code, I'd say that you don't either. Interesting problem. Perhaps @scanny has some input?

Comment: @MadPhysicist , Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: No problem. I will check back on this question periodically because I am curious about how it will work out. Just when I though I had a grasp on how python-docx did the Python-to-xml mapping, I find something like this.

Comment: Also, nice user name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No custom style has been defined on your paragraph so a default [latent style](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/styles/index.html) is applied and this kind of style is read-only because it has no real definition in the document.

Apply a custom style on your run or your paragraph and you will be able to customize it. For a run, you have to create character style (`WD_STYLE_TYPE.CHARACTER`).

```
# create the document and the custom style
document = Document()
mystyle = document.styles.add_style('mystyle', WD_STYLE_TYPE.CHARACTER)
...
...
# apply the custom on the run
run.style = mystyle
font = run.font
font.rtl = True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @DLDR for ur answer :)

Comment: @ Mad Physicist, this answer fixed the issue :)

Comment: ,How can set the Text alignmnet to be right, i see in the documentation that it can be addded on the paragraph level only<br> Is there away to set the style for all statements in the documnet without define style per each one,

Comment: Ok, I haven't seen that in the documentation but you can also solve your problem by creating a paragraph style and set it to your paragraph.

Comment: Yes, but mt problem is to set the paragraph right aligned and RTL , couldn't mix them

Comment: For now, the solution I think which could work would be to create a base document in Ms Word and modifying the default normal style in it as needed. Then using Python-docx, I would use it as base document and inject all the new text in it.

Comment: NameError: name 'WD_STYLE_TYPE' is not defined

Comment: @keramat from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE