# Python- Change right-to-left in a word file using docx module

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx

I want to make a paragraph, right-to-left. I'm using docx module.
I tried:

```
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
```

But it just change the align. How can i edit "right-to-left"?

Comment: Have you tried (manually) creating a right-to-left style and then in your code applying that style to the para?

Comment: **barny** No. How to do it ??

Comment: Haven’t the faintest idea. Otherwise I might have added an answer. Must be a way to apply styles in the docx API. Go investigate!

Comment: **barny** I investigated. But I did not find anything about adding a new style which does not exist in the default template of docx. How to add and define one?

Comment: Because I did not find any style that changes right-to-left.

Comment: What I meant was to manually edit the template so you have a style that is right-to-left, then in your code apply the style to a selection. Or go searching for other answers about `word docx rtl`

Comment: Like this q and a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985320/python-docx-set-the-text-direction-rtl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python-docx set the text direction RTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985320/python-docx-set-the-text-direction-rtl)