# cannot make text rtl with python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.7, right-to-left, python-docx

yes i know many questions about this issue exists but i couldn't make any of them work.

i have python 3.7 and python-docx 0.8.11.
i have tried many solutions including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985320/python-docx-set-the-text-direction-rtl)

```
from docx import Document, enum
document = Document()
mystyle = document.styles.add_style('mystyle', enum.style.WD_STYLE_TYPE.CHARACTER)
run = document.add_paragraph().add_run(text)
run.style = mystyle
font = run.font
font.rtl = True
document.save('test.docx')
```

also

```
from docx import Document, enum
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT

doc = Document()

rtlstyle = doc.styles.add_style('rtl', enum.style.WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)
rtlstyle.font.rtl = True
p = doc.add_paragraph(text)
p.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.RIGHT
p.style = rtlstyle
doc.save('test.docx')
```

nothing worked so far

Comment: `i couldn't make any of them work` how so? error? not rtl? any difference between the two solutions provided? expected vs actutal

Comment: no errors it just writes it left to right

Comment: no difference between the two that i could see except that in one of the solutions the alignment is to the right

Answer (score -1):

see this : https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73133074/revisions

also as mensiond [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42556063/right-to-left-and-left-to-right-printed-nicely) put this before your text:  u'\u202B' + "your text"

or  u'\u202E' if didn't work